# How to save XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

Anyone know how I can create and save XML using PHP? I need something like this:

```
<jukebox>
  <track source="" artist="" album="" title="" />
  <track source="" artist="" album="" title="" />
  <track source="" artist="" album="" title="" />
  <track source="" artist="" album="" title="" />
</jukebox>
```

Comment: uummmm something like what? I think we need more than that to figure stuff out.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asXML.php

Comment: you should go and 'accept' the answer below. Click the checkmark on the answer that helped you out the most. It's how the reputation system works here. By doing so, you'll encourage people to answer your questions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for.

```
    //Creates XML string and XML document using the DOM 
    $dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 

    //add root
    $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('Root'));

    //add NodeA element to Root
    $nodeA = $dom->createElement('NodeA');
    $root->appendChild($nodeA);

    // Appending attr1 and attr2 to the NodeA element
    $attr = $dom->createAttribute('attr1');
    $attr->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('some text'));
    $nodeA->appendChild($attr);
/*
** insert more nodes
*/

    $dom->formatOutput = true; // set the formatOutput attribute of domDocument to true

    // save XML as string or file 
    $test1 = $dom->saveXML(); // put string in test1
    $dom->save('test1.xml'); // save as file
```

For more information, have a look at the [DOM Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

To do what you want:

```
    //Creates XML string and XML document using the DOM 
    $dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 

    //add root == jukebox
    $jukebox = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('jukebox'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayWithTracks); $i++) {

        //add track element to jukebox
        $track = $dom->createElement('track');
        $jukebox->appendChild($track);

        // Appending attributes to track
        $attr = $dom->createAttribute('source');
        $attr->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($arrayWithTracks[$i]['source']));
        $track->appendChild($attr);
        $attr = $dom->createAttribute('artist');
        $attr->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($arrayWithTracks[$i]['artist']));
        $track->appendChild($attr);
        $attr = $dom->createAttribute('album');
        $attr->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($arrayWithTracks[$i]['album']));
        $track->appendChild($attr);
        $attr = $dom->createAttribute('title');
        $attr->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($arrayWithTracks[$i]['title']));
        $track->appendChild($attr);
    }

    $dom->formatOutput = true; // set the formatOutput attribute of domDocument to true

    // save XML as string or file 
    $test1 = $dom->saveXML(); // put string in test1
    $dom->save('test1.xml'); // save as file
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank's vfn thats exactly what I want and so quick

Thank's

Comment: Hi vfn, thanks again for your response and solution to my question, however if it's ok with you can I pick at your brains a little bit more.



The XML file you helped me with would normally be populated with music files "MP3" in a directory that is called using PHP, I can get 

a list of all the files in a directory using PHP but how would I then add that information to the XML file? the only information I would 

really need is the source/location of the file's as for the rest I will be using an MP3 metadata class, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean? I couldn't understand the your question!

Comment: Ok, with the XML file that you helped me with above I would now like to be able to add information from all file's that are in a directory on a web server to it, the main field would be "The source" location of the MP3 file's, so in theory looping through and listing all files in a directory and adding them to the XML file.

Comment: Hey Malcolm, It looks like you know the answer to your question. Please, have a look at the edit that I've done to my answer and let me know if it's OK. It's now iterating on an array that will have all the tracks, and for each track a new node will be added to the root of the xml.

Comment: Again I would like to thank you, I now have it sorted, I would be still working on it if it wasn't for you, thank's ;)

Comment: @vfn Is any way to convert the object to XML? Thanks

Comment: @Gem, could you please elaborate your question? The object is already an XML object. The last two lines of the code sample show (1) how to get it as a string, and (2) how to save it to a file.

Comment: @vfn my code : https://justpaste.it/43kpl, can you pls help me to convert objects to xml formate.

Comment: @Gem Please create a new question explaining what the problem you are trying to solve is. Add your code and what the expected result would be. This way you'll be able to get an appropriate response for your problem. Thanks!

Comment: @vfn My account not working properly, i can't able to post. Can you pls help me. I did with soap but values getting objects, how to convert into XML.