# Create XML with php variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I am wanting to create and save, to the server, an xml file.  I understand I should use javascript but am not sure exactly how to code it.

Scenario:
I have a php page with variables, $firstname and $lastname for example. 
So in the php:
    $firstname = "John";
    $lastname ="Doe";

I want to have a javascript that when fired will create and save an xml file.

I found the below post and it got me headed in the right direction.

[How to save XML using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552755/how-to-save-xml-using-php)

Can anyone help me.  I greatly appreciate some direction.

Additionally is it possible to have it outputjust like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form1>
   <fname>John</fname>
   <lname>Doe</lname>
</form1>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Javascript if you can do it with PHP? Besides, Javascript won't be able to save the file. Only your server-side (PHP) can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a client-side technology, PHP is server side. The question you linked is a good place to start, you'll want to use DomDocument and/or simplexml. If there is client side interaction, you'll still have to post the data to the server and store the file there.